# How to make an install file (made from IExpress) run as administrator on another computer

Tags: c#, windows, security, iexpress

I made a custom install program for a product our company develops.  Because we deal with customers that don't understand zip files, I've created an IExpress executable that unzips everything and launches the setup.exe

The problem I'm facing is that my setup program needs admin credentials (checking registry to see if keys exist, executing a batch script, etc).  Up until now I've always informed customers to right-click and select "Run as Administrator".  Is there a way to do this automatically, so I don't have to instruct them to right-click?  Customers don't like following instructions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in sort, the answer is no, if they need to run as admin they will have to right click and run as admin, even if they are an admin on their machine.  re installers, I would recommend using WIX Installer which is a VS addin that is tricky to get to grips with at first, but then pretty simple once you know what youre doing with it.

Answer (score 2):

In the app.manifest of any C# solution there is a `requestedExecutionLevel` key. Changing the value of this key to `requireAdministrator` will always run that application as an administrator. However, this means if a user that doesn't have admin access can't run that application. Alternatively you can set it to `highestAvailable` which will run for all users but if the user has admin rights then it will run as admin. Hope this helps!

Comment: This half worked. It did get it so my Setup file requires admin privileges.  Unfortunately there's no way to force IExpress to use admin priveleges, so it just causes the install to fail.

Comment: Maybe if your Setup file is given to iexpress as "setup.exe," you can change it to "cmd /c setup.exe." iexpress will see that cmd.exe doesn't elevate its own level, and probably run it, without considering what setup.exe will do.

Answer (score 0):

I will simply expand on what rmn36 has said.  To make an IExpress generated self-extracting CAB package request for admin privileges immediately on execution, use Visual Studio (Community version 2019 works) to edit the manifest of the executable.

From Visual Studio: File->Open your executable.
Open (click the + sign to the left of) the manifest (Windows 10 IExpress labels this RT_MANIFEST).  There should be a '1' underneath RT_MANIFEST, double-click on it to bring up the editor.  Place your cursor in the right-hand column with the text to edit normally instead of in hex.  You can insert, delete, etc. even though you see binary; it is not fixed length.

Locate the requestedExecutionLevel key and set the level property as shown (by default it is set to "asInvoker"):

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
```

Save the executable and now users no longer need to right-click and "Run as Administrator" - Windows automatically prompts.